# iOS 7 navigation bar style to look like navigation controller nav bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When using the navigation controller or embedding a view controller in navigation controller, the navigation bar light grey color covers the status bar also (the carrier, time, battery, etc).  When dragging a navigation bar onto the view controller, the status bar is still white.  You can't change the height of the navigation bar...so how can I make everything look and feel the same?  Here's the two images:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, Chat shows that white space above the nav bar, whereas Social doesn't...any workout for this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case navigation bar looks like non-transparent.
Please check properties of navigation bar and/or initialization of this bar to be sure that it's transparent.

Comment: I solved it by adding a subview with the same color as the default navbar color below the navbar...Looks the same.  Do you mean if it's Translucent?

Comment: Yes. But exists some another ways to set opacity/transparency for this bar.